# Add OJBDC to Classpath when Executing .jar

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, classpath

I'm trying to develop a Java application that connects to an Oracle database and executes a function. If I run the application in Eclipse it works, but when I try to run the .jar in Windows Command Prompt I get "Error encountered: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found".

I am passing the path of all .jar files shown in Maven Dependencies in Eclipse when I execute in the command line.

**Steps**

1. Execute "mvn clean install -U"
2. Execute .jar from Target directory with "java -cp  example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11-sources.jarC:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3-sources.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/ojdbc10/19.3.0.0/ojdbc10-19.3.0.0-sources.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/ucp/19.3.0.0/ucp-19.3.0.0-sources.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/oraclepki/19.3.0.0/oraclepki-19.3.0.0-sources.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/osdt_cert/19.3.0.0/osdt_cert-19.3.0.0-sources.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/osdt_core/19.3.0.0/osdt_core-19.3.0.0-sources.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/simplefan/19.3.0.0/simplefan-19.3.0.0-sources.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/ons/19.3.0.0/ons-19.3.0.0-sources.jar function.example.App"
3. OR (as suggested below) execute .jar from Target directory with "java -cp  example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/ojdbc10/19.3.0.0/ojdbc10-19.3.0.0.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/ucp/19.3.0.0/ucp-19.3.0.0.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/oraclepki/19.3.0.0/oraclepki-19.3.0.0.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/osdt_cert/19.3.0.0/osdt_cert-19.3.0.0.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/osdt_core/19.3.0.0/osdt_core-19.3.0.0.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/simplefan/19.3.0.0/simplefan-19.3.0.0.jar;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc/ons/19.3.0.0/ons-19.3.0.0.jar function.example.App"

**Application**

```
package function.example;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = checkForPalindrome("racecar");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error encountered: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {

        Properties prop = ReadPropertyFile();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("db.URL"), prop.getProperty("db.user"),
                    prop.getProperty("db.password"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error encountered: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static String checkForPalindrome(String word) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "{? = call CHECKFORPALINDROME(?)}";
        try (Connection conn = getConnection(); java.sql.CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);) {
            stmt.setString(2, word);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.execute();
            String stmtResult = stmt.getString(1);
            return stmtResult;
        }
    }

    private static Properties ReadPropertyFile() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:\\config.properties")) {
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error encountered: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error encountered: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

**POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>function</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ODB-function-example-pom</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.ojdbc/ojdbc10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>8</release> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>function.example.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Fix**

Removed the ojdbc10 dependency from my pom. Downloaded ojdbc8 from the Oracle website (I couldn't seem to download it using mvnrepository), added these .jar files manually to Eclipse and to the classpath when executing in the Command Line.

java -cp example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\me\Desktop\ojdbc8-full* function.example.App

Comment: You have select sources instead of compiled jars for your dependencies. That is not correct.

Comment: To clarify in Elliott's comment, your classpath has a lot of `XXX-sources.jar` files. They contain source code needed by the IDE, e.g. when debugging, but is not needed to run the code. You do however need the actual code, so remove the `-sources` part and add `XXX.jar` instead. E.g. instead of `ojdbc10-19.3.0.0-sources.jar`, use `ojdbc10-19.3.0.0.jar`. Do that for all of them.

Comment: Thanks, I did just try without the non -sources .jar files but I still get the same error. I added the command I tried to step 3.

Comment: If you fixed it by replacing ojdbc10 with ojdbc8, then you're executing using Java 8. The numbers in the Oracle JDBC artifact indicate the target Java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that you have `jar` without dependencies, so your oracles `ojdbc` classes are not included in the final `jar`. What you want to have is a **"fat jar"**.

The way to do it - to add maven plugin which will pack all the dependencies in app `jar`. This could be achieved with `maven-assembly-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- get all project dependencies -->
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>function.example.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So one you ran `mvn package`, you will have `jar-with-dependencies` artifact, which will contain all the dependencies.

### Update

Your app is unable to discover driver class in the runtime, so you also have to load it manually. It usually looks something like that:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Driver driver = (Driver) clazz.newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually had another question about trying to get this working with Maven Shade https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864273/maven-shade-with-ojdbc-dependency. However, for now I am trying just to get the basics working. If I am including the ojdbc classes in the ClassPath it should still work without being a fat jar?

Comment: Once I implemented your update I was getting an error about mismatching versions, I think because I was using ojdbc10 and Java 8 was specified in my POM. The ojdbc8 on mvnrepository didn't seem to actually exist, but when I downloaded it fro the Oracle website and added it to my classpath, my code was able to run from the command line. It runs even without the manual load step.

Comment: Not exactly what I've suggested, but I hope my answer was helpful for you :)